# Abroad or onboard

Tags: word-usage

In the following sentence I have to find the error

> The ship sank and everyone abroad drowned.

I think instead of abroad **onboard** should be used, and it is the only error. But the answer given in my book is

In the place of **drowned**, **was drowned** should be used. But I think its incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to ask about *aboard* and *onboard.* "Abroad" means something rather different.

Alternatively, perhaps you have misread *aboard* as *abroad.*  Have a look at your dictionary.  They are different words.

Personally, I find *onboard* abhorrent, and *on board* slightly less so.  *Aboard* is a great word and deserves more attention, like its kin *abaft, abeam, athwart,* and *astern,* as well as *above, about, around, along,* and, yes, *abroad,* and probably others I'm not thinking of just now.

As to the assertion that the sentence should read *was drowned* instead of *drowned,* that is not correct.  It might be correct if your goal is to sound like someone who was writing in the early 19th century or earlier.  Either *drowned* or *was drowned* would be correct in that sentence, but *drowned* is rather more normal for modern English.

Both are possible because *drown* has both transitive and intransitive sentences.  Intransitively, it means to be suffocated in liquid (usually water):

> The person drowned in the lake.  Witnesses heard cries of "Help, I'm drowning!"

Transitively, it means to suffocate something or someone in liquid (usually water):

> The murderer drowned the victim in the lake.  Witnesses heard cries of "Help, I'm being drowned!"

Comment: It would never have occurred to me that 'was drowned' was all that archaic.